# How can I validate client certificate in python using cherrypy web framework?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, https, cherrypy

I have a web server running via python CherryPy web framework which has to validate each client request. What I wanted to do is to get the certificate from client https request and validate it against server's rootca. How to do it? A sample code will be very helpful.